# CSS ONLY - Sticky menu changes background on scroll

Tags: css

I am trying to fix an issue on a website that only supports HTML/CSS.
No script is allowed.
The problem is, sticky menu is transparent, and when the user scroll down, it blends in to the text. So I need to have a background when the user scrolls down.

I have the HTML like this:

```
<div aria-label="secondary" id="secondary" class="top-navigation">
  <div class="top-navigation-box">
    <div class="navbar-header"> 
      <button
        class="top-navigation-toggle navbar-toggle collapsed"
        data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#my-top-nav"
        aria-expanded="false"
      >
        More
      </button>
    </div>

      <ul class="top-navigation-utilities nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="color: #f2f2f2">Team<span class="caret"></span></a></li>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="dropdown-header" style="color: #146eb4">About</li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="color: #f2f2f2">Support<span class="caret"></span></a></li>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

And the CSS trying to do the magic is like:

```
.top-navigation {
  background: transparent;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  height: 5rem;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}

.top-navigation.scrolled {
  background-color: red;
}
```

But it doesn't change the background at all.
Any suggestions?

Comment: There is lacking in your code. Also, add image/draft of the final output you want to achieve.

Comment: How can the scrolled class be set without using e.g. some Javascript?

Comment: Is there a reason for not giving it a background all the time (whether scrolled or not?).

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS refers to a class that doesn't exist in your HTML

```
.top-navigation.scrolled {
  background-color: red;
}
```

This rule only applies to an element that has both the `top-navigation` and the `scrolled` class.

For example, if you change it to the following, your rule will match.

```
.top-navigation {
  background-color: red;
}
```

I'm not sure how you will be able to apply the `scrolled` class dynamically without any scripting?